# Getting "1004 Cannot run the macro..." on analysis toolpak suddenly

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

As of yesterday, I had a working macro that generated histograms using analysis toolpak (VBA). As you can see below, the analysis toolpak VBA add in is enabled, and I have set a reference in VBA.

[image]
[image]

The file is saved as .xlsm (macro enabled) and I can produce histograms without a macro:

[image]

But if I record a macro to make a histogram, I get this same error. This is happening for all functions within the analysis toolpak. What happened here?

Comment: What happens when click on `Debug`?

Comment: Stepping through just stops at the first atpvbean function and throws that error.

Comment: The most confusing part of this is that it was working yesterday. The only change I made was saving the file as a new filename, at which point I began working on the new file (and haven't touched this one).

Comment: Have you verified that macros didn't get disabled? File -> options -> trust center -> trust center settings -> macro settings.

Comment: Does any other macros work?

Comment: Might be worth trying to remove the reference and then add it again.  I've seen stranger things.

Comment: Well, Excel does strange things in his cells. By saving it as a new filename, maybe some references were changed or even deleted. It doesn't even give the Macro name in the error, so I guess a reference has gone rogue.

Comment: @MatthewD Macros are fully trusted and I've already tried to reset the reference.

Comment: @EngJon I'm going to look into that I don't know where it would be happening.

Comment: @99moorem The macro works up until the atpvbaen functions.

Comment: This is the point where i create a new workbook and copy the code into it and add the references. If it works in the new one you know something has gone awry with the other.  Also maybe try it on another computer.

Comment: @MatthewD Looks like the references got screwed up in the copy I was talking about too. Oh boy. Going to make a new workbook and see what happens.

Comment: It could be the references in Excel, to the library, got screwed up, or, the reference itself.  Did it come from the installation of a program, that may be screwed up.  May need reinstalled. As to how it could get messed up, any number of things. Maybe virus scan didn't like something about it and 'cleaned' it.  I've seen that before.  Let us know if you get it.

Comment: @MatthewD I "solved" the problem (although I don't know the root cause). For now I'm going to accept my own answer but I hope someone can shine a light on what interaction between the add-in and my workbook caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

... I'm going to have to call this one solved. Very VERY strange error that must be related to **this**

[image]

error message I received when I disabled both the analysis toolpak and the analysis toolpak for VBA add-ins. My code is back in working order after disabling/re-enabling these add-ins. Maybe someone knows exactly why this is happening, but I have to guess that add-ins are handled as hidden workbooks with VBA functions and *something* strange happened to that workbook. No clue.

Comment: If it wasn't for goofy stuff like that we wouldn't have jobs.

Answer (score 0):

my issue was that when I run the macro (to create a histogram), the first time, it runs normally but when rerun it, it gets the error, mentioned above.
I solved it by unchecking atpvbaen.xls from the references.